# Bootstrap + jQuery sortable and resizable

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In the below jsfiddle I am facing an issue while vertically resizing the panels on the right hand side. Check image below.

i am using the below code for sortable and resizable

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$('.turf_chart_sort_container').resizable();
```

[image: 1]

The behavior is correct for left side panels.

[image: 1]

http://jsfiddle.net/sarvesht/RFFp6/

How can i fix the issue for right side panels?

Comment: This is a common problem, check http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: Does isotope support resize of the divs? Could'nt find any examples for  drag drop + resize.

Comment: drag drop resize use yours, for positioning properly use isotope